# How to do equality space between the top and the bottom

Tags: html, css

There is a top (Logo, Menu, etc), then content and then something in the bottom.
How can I do that the space between the content to the top and the space between the content to the bottom, will be the same?

Thanks!

Comment: And your HTML/ CSS code is?

Comment: Thats long code... but I'll going to do divs. I mean: <div id="top">, <div id="content", <div id="bottom"> @Mi-Creativity

Comment: CSS padding / margin ? Show us your code and where are you failing. Also you could try to reproduce your problem in a JSFiddle.

Comment: Thats long code... but I'll going to do divs. I mean: <div id="top">, <div id="content", <div id="bottom"> @pablito.aven

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spacing between elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114664/spacing-between-elements)

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the CSS `margin` property to space contents from each other.

Padding does the same but *within* the element and not *around* the element.

What you'll want (based on your **html** from the comments)

```
#content {
    margin: 20px 0;
}
```

if the content also has to be centered while having this space you can change the `0` to `auto` like this:

```
#content {
    margin: 20px auto;
}
```

This was not that hard, [googling for about 1.4 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114664/spacing-between-elements) gave me a good result when looking for '*space between elements*'.

Here @ SO we answer every question with love except those that show no research or effort, seemingly you have put in effort provided your content but there is already something *on stackoverflow* about it (so you're asking the same question - before posting - check internet <3)

Comment: But I dont know how much px I should do to make the text in the middle...

Answer (score 1):

Probably want something like this, but without some reference code it's hard to help.

```
.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, ill check it and then update you

Comment: With position: relative it doesnt work. I tried absolute and its really make them to be in the middle, but now they are in the left side (and I want them to be in the center). What can I do?

Comment: Yeah I meant absolute, my bad. Any chance you can make a http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: @Roy I've also edited the code so you can try that.

Comment: Andrew, thanks. It works in a full screen, but when I minimize my screen its just not looking good, not responsive

Comment: you have suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS `margin` or `padding` depending on the result you want to achieve, by setting same values to `top` and `bottom` `padding` or `margin`

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/n0qe06hp/1/)

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#top {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
#content {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #090;
  padding: 100px 0 100px 0;/* padding top, right, bottom, left values*/
}
#bottom {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #999;
}
```

```html
<div id="top">Top</div>
<div id="content">Content
  <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil odio, quidem totam fugit officiis expedita atque ullam quae. Rem, quasi distinctio suscipit. Qui cupiditate dolores quod fugiat accusantium nobis esse.</div>
<div id="bottom">Bottom</div>
```

The `padding` adds its values to your `div#content` evenly to have same distance on top and bottom, however if you don't want to stretch the `div#content` and just have spaces on top and bottom of it then replace the `padding` CSS line with this: [**JS Fiddle 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/n0qe06hp/2/)

```
margin:100px 0 100px 0; /* margin top, right, bottom, left values*/
```